# Multiple plots with insets within Show

Tags: plotting

I wonder why I cannot see the second inset by using this code

```
shadow = Rasterize[
   Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Bottom, MeshShading -> None, 
    MeshStyle -> None, Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> None, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
    ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {20, 20}}], Background -> None];
shadow2 = 
  Rasterize[
   Plot[1 - x, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Bottom, MeshShading -> None, 
    MeshStyle -> None, Axes -> None, PlotStyle -> None, 
    PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
    ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {20, 20}}], Background -> None];
Show[
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  Epilog -> Inset[shadow]],
 Plot[1 - x, {x, 0, 1}, PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, 
  Epilog -> Inset[shadow2]],
 PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {20, 20}}
 ]
```

Thanks, for the information.
[image]

This question has nothing to do with

[Plot Option Precedence while combining Plots with `Show[]`](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/128/plot-option-precedence-while-combining-plots-with-show)

since my problem is specific about superposition of graphs by using insets and not about the option precedence. My graphs should graphically superimpose since they have been created with transparency. Note if one moves both the insets to an Epilog-> in Show[] the wanted result is displayed correctely.

Comment: This question ([Plot with Epilog doesn't show up in Show](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/82471/27951)) most directly duplicates your issue; a full explanation can be found here: [Plot Option Precedence while combining Plots with `Show[]`](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/128/27951). More specifically, what you are trying to do seems more easily accomplished using the [`Filling` option](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Filling.html) of `Plot` as Kay showed below.

Comment: @MarcoB so the answer is: to move all the Epilog in the first graphic displayed by Show

Comment: Yep, pretty much, or possibly better, to add the objects that you were trying to show with `Epilog` to a separate `Graphics` expression inside `Show`, i.e. `Show[plot1, plot2, Graphics[epilogstuff]]`.

Comment: MarcoB, I've tried your suggestion, but still nothing appears

Comment: seeing your edit, the issue is exactly about option precedence. *you can not have two epilogs, only the first one is used*. You need to put `Epilog -> {Inset[shadow2], Inset[shadow]}` either in the *first* `Plot` or as an option to `Show`

Answer (score 6):

I just shortened your code a bit, is this what you were searching for?
Though it's not directly the answer to your question...

```
pl[a_] := Plot[a, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Bottom];
Show[pl[x], pl[1 - x]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Looking at your existing code, a few suggestions present themselves:

1. **Do not rasterize the shadows**; you gain nothing by it.
2. Place plot options that you want to apply to all plots within `Show`, not within each plot.
3. Remove redundant options.

If you do that, then you are left with:

```
shadow = Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Bottom];
shadow2 = Plot[1 - x, {x, 0, 1}, Filling -> Bottom];

Show[
 shadow, shadow2,
 Plot[x, {x, 0, 1}],
 Plot[1 - x, {x, 0, 1}],     
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {20, 20}}
]
```

But now you realize that you are duplicating your efforts for no gain! The `shadow*` plots already do all you need:

```
Show[
 shadow, shadow2,
 PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}}, PlotRangePadding -> 0, 
 ImagePadding -> {{20, 20}, {20, 20}}
]
```

The you realize that you do not need to use `Show` here at all: you can simply `Plot` two functions at once:

```
Plot[
 {x, 1 - x}, {x, 0, 1},
 Filling -> Bottom
]
```

[image: two colors]

This is not yet what you wanted, though, because `Plot` automatically colors the two functions differently. We need to tell it to **use the same color for both plots**. We can do that by specifying a single `PlotStyle` directive to use for all plots; in particular, we will indicate that we want to use the first of the standard indexed colors (`ColorData[97]`), i.e. `ColorData[97][1]`:

```
Plot[
 {x, 1 - x}, {x, 0, 1},
 Filling -> Bottom,
 PlotStyle -> ColorData[97][1]
]
```

[image: one color]